# Table with automatic \hline on given height and words transfer handling

Tags: tables, formatting, tabularx

I need to create a 3 columns of the same width and split it into cells of the same hight, so when I print text and formulas it will automatically placed in the next cell if it doesn't fit. So when I print something in the bottom cell and it doesn't fit, it should be placed in next right up cell. How can I do this?

```
                                       PAGE
  --------------------------------------------------------------------
 | This is the text that I want to be | Suppose this is next text from|
 | placed in cells specific way.      | left bottom cell, but it also |
 | Suppose this part of the text is   | doesn't fit with the cell     |
 | perfectly fit with the height of   | hight, so it's transfered the |
 | the cell, but for example from here| next right up cell. <ENTER>   |
  --------------------------------------------------------------------
 | THIS word doesn't fit with the     | And the text continued here.  |
 | height of previous cell and and    |                               |
 | shouldn't be placed the next string|                               |
 | in previous cell, but should be put|                               |
 | the first string in the cell below |                               |                 
  ------------------------------------ -------------------------------
```

Comment: it's a rather strange requirement, without the horizontal rules it would just be a standard 3-column multicols, but vertically splitting it at some fixed height interval makes it harder (and impossible if there is anything unbreakable such as a math display or image that doesn't fit)

Comment: I need to split my page in blocks of fixed width and height and provide my text to jump next block if it doesn't fit the height

Comment: most likely the easiest way is to specify that your page height is your block height and then re-assemble later with two (?) of these virtual pages per actual page. (You haven't said how many blocks fit on a page)

Comment: 5cm is block width and 3.5cm - block height. There are about 24 blocks on one page

Comment: is this for some kind of n-up card printing, if the use case is met by specifying a page size of 5cm x 3.5cm using the geometry package and then printing 24 pages per page using your print driver (or a pdf re-arrangement tool) then that is going to be the best way. If you need combined headers and footers spanning your 24 blocks then you may need to do it in latex which is possible but more fragile and more likely to clash with any other packages that you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify your 5cm x 3.5cm page size using the geometry package, which will make each of your "blocks" a page in the pdf, then specify a 3x6 layout of pdf pages per physical page while printing the pdf.